# GVRAudioEngine + Swift

Tags: swift, audio, google-vr, google-vr-sdk, resonance-audio

everyone
I'm trying to import GVRAudioEngine included in Google VR SDK to my swift project.
I installed GVRAudioSDK from cocoapods,then import 'GVRaudioEngine'.But It doesn't work.
Does anyone know how to import them?

I'm using Mojave（10.14.1） , xcode10.1 , Swift4.2.1

Thank you.

Comment: Don't just say "it doesn't work", say "**what you have done** and **what you have seen** that make you know 'it doesn't work'".

Comment: Thank you for rep! And sorry that my consideration is insufficient.  I want to create a swift project including GVRAudioEngine. So I tried to install GVRAudioSDK to my xcode proj through cocoapods. Maybe, My podsFile worked correctly. Then , I wrote 'import GVRAudioEngine' in my swift file. But xcode says 'No such module GVRAudioEngine'. Nothing to do I can. Please tell me what should I do. I'm still a beginner on programming...